# Scalable way to train graph embeddings

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, graphs, embeddings

I have a [use-case](https://github.com/aditya-grover/node2vec) to train graph embeddings, looking for a way to do it in PyTorch and TensorFlow. The restriction is the methodology should incorporate edge weights in calculating transition probability. Can someone please advise the best framework/library to do? The node2vec implementation by the authors is in spark only, however, my current ML pipeline is more PyTorch/TF friendly.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this is what you need but I know of the [Ampligraph](https://github.com/Accenture/AmpliGraph/) library:

> Python [library](https://docs.ampligraph.org) for Representation Learning on Knowledge Graphs